# check if a view is showing with windowmanager

Tags: android, overlay, android-windowmanager

How I can know if a view is being displayed before adding with WindowManager?
I need put a overlay in native Dialer but sometimes the native dialer put above mi custom view, I solved this by adding the element several times with WindowManager but sometimes the view is displayed twice.

Thanks!!

```
private void callStartIncomingCallScreen(Context context, String incomingNumber) {
    startIncomingCallScreen(context, incomingNumber);

    Timer timer = new Timer();

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        timer.schedule(new StartIncomingCallScreenTimerTask(context, incomingNumber), 100 * i);
    }
}


class StartIncomingCallScreenTimerTask extends TimerTask {

    private Context context;
    private String incomingNumber;

    StartIncomingCallScreenTimerTask(Context context, String incomingNumber) {
        this.context = context;
        this.incomingNumber = incomingNumber;
    }

    public void run() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, IncomingCallGuiService.class);
        context.startService(intent);
    }
}
```

And in the IncomingCallGuiService i add the view like this:

```
final LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(
      LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
      LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
      LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
      PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);



WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
// add the overlay
wm.addView(view, params);
```

Comment: The code isn't indented/formatted properly... it is difficult to read.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can check it with the view that you inflate. You can use `view.isShown()` for check it. When you add the view with `windowManager.addView(yourView)` this return true when you call `isShown()`.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: I think it's view.isShown() (at least for the latest api)